# How do I get a list of strings as inputs for a function and getting a list returned for the function

Tags: python

I have the following equation below to get the following results:

```
Input: 3 ft
Output: [3, 'ft']
```

```
def parse_measurement(split_list):
    split_list = (input_value.split())
    try:
        split_list[0] = int(split_list[0])
    except ValueError:
        split_list[0] = float(split_list[0])
    return split_list
```

Now how do I go about editing it, so I can get the following results from this input below?

```
Input: 3 ft, 5 ft, 8.3 ft
Output: [(2, "ft"), (5, "ft"), (8.3, "ft")]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

You already have a function that can handle a single value. Given multiple values, you can call that function multiple times with a list comprehension. To get the individual arguments, just split the list on `","`:

```
def parse_measurement(input_value):
    split_list = input_value.split()
    try:
        split_list[0] = int(split_list[0])
    except ValueError:
        split_list[0] = float(split_list[0])
    return split_list


input_text = "3 ft, 5 ft, 8.3 ft"

output = [parse_measurement(s) for s in input_text.split(',')]

# [[3, 'ft'], [5, 'ft'], [8.3, 'ft']]
```

This has the advantage of adhering to the [single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) — your function does one thing, converts a measure and unit to a list. Rather than complicate that by having it deal with different kinds of input, move that functionality somewhere else and leave the function to deal with its single responsibility.

Comment: def parse_measurement(output):
    split_list = (input_value.split())
    try:
        split_list[0] = int(split_list[0])
    except ValueError:
        split_list[0] = float(split_list[0])
    output = [parse_measurement(s) for s in input_value.split(',')]
    return output
I wrote it like this, and my outputs look like [800.23, 'seconds', '5.3', 'ft,', '3', 'ft')

Answer (score 0):

The underlining function that you have is correct.

You can utilise the same function within a `for` loop, passing the string with a delimiter you want to split as input

```
def parse_measurement(split_list):
    split_list = (input_value.split())
    try:
        split_list[0] = int(split_list[0])
    except ValueError:
        split_list[0] = float(split_list[0])
    return split_list

>>> inp = "2 ft,3 ft , 8.3 ft"
>>> res = []
>>> for val in inp.split(","):
       res += [parse_measurement(val)]

res = [(2, "ft"), (5, "ft"), (8.3, "ft")]
```

Comment: Why not just `res.append(parse_measurement(val))`? OR even better - `res = [parse_measurement(val) for val in inp.split(",")]`

Comment: Yep , this is another classic pythonic way. I tend to append lists with `+=` rather than append , never thought it to be different then append if any?

Comment: Surely the outcome is the same, but I believe using `+=` is a bit more wasteful (of course too critical to become a bottleneck is most codes...)

Answer (score 0):

If the input is going to be a comma separated list, then you'll also want to split on the commas (`,`) and iterate over that set:

```
def parse_measurement(input):
    measurements = []
    for measurement in input.split(','):
        split_list = (measurement.split())
        if split_list[0].isdigit():
            to_add = (int(split_list[0]), "ft")
            measurements.append(to_add)
    
    return measurements
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
import re

def parse_mes(input_value):
  y = re.split('\,\s*',input_value)
  split_list = []
  for x in y:
    try:
      split_list.append((int(x.split()[0]),x.split()[1]))
    except ValueError:
      split_list.append((float(x.split()[0]),x.split()[1]))
   
  return split_list
```

```
print(parse_mes('3 ft, 8.6 ft'))
```